# Number of multiplicative inverses in $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

Is there a formula for the number of multiplicative inverses (invertibles) in $\mathbb{Z}_m$? I know one way would be to count for how many elements $n \in \mathbb{Z}_m$, $0<n<m$ the following equation satisfies: $\gcd (n,m)=1$.

Comment: Yep.  A number is invertible if and only if it is relatively prime to $m$.  So there are $\phi(m)$ numbers with inverses.

Comment: $\varphi(N) = N \prod_{p|N, p \text{prime}} (1-\frac{1}{p})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common formula is $\phi(m) = m\prod_{p|n;p\ prime}(1-\frac 1p)$ (So, for example, $\phi(24) = 24(1-\frac 12)(1-\frac 13) = 24\cdot \frac 12\cdot \frac23=8$.)  But I personally prefer $\phi(\prod p_i^{a_i}) =\prod p_i^{a_i-1}\prod(p_i - 1)$.  (So, for example $\phi (24) = \phi(2^3\cdot 3) = (2^2\cdot 3^0)(2-1)(3-1) = 8$.)

These handy rules will never let you down:  If $p$ is prime then $\phi(p) = p-1$.  And $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1)$.  ANd if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ then $\phi(mn) = \phi(m)\cdot\phi(n)$.

Comment: Awesome! That's very interesting! How do we know that $\phi(m)$ always returns an integer? especially when we have $1-\frac 1p$ in the formula.

Comment: $n(1  -\frac 1p) = n\frac {p-1}p=\frac np(p-1)$. As the primes are distinct we will never have an issue with $\frac n{p_1p_2p_3....}$ not being an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is precisely what the Euler totient function $\phi(n)$ counts. It is also easy to compute given a prime factorisation of $n$ as $\phi(p^n)=p^n-p^{n-1}$ for prime $p$, and $\phi$ is multiplicative.

Comment: And notoriously hard to compute if $n$ is large & difficult to factor. ;)